# Scan for duplicate strings in a file

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I have been having a problem with the next step in the logic of my code. Basically I'm supposed to examine each line of a file looking for consecutive tokens on the same line, and print the duplicate token along with the number of times it consecutively occurs. Non repeated tokens aren't printed.
here's a sample file

```
/*
 * sometext.txt
 * hello how how are you you you you
I I I am Jack's Jack's smirking smirking smirking smirking revenge
bow wow wow yippee yippee yo yippee yippee yay yay yay
one fish two fish red fish blue fish
It's the Muppet Show, wakka wakka wakka
 */
```

and here's some code that i've written.

```
package chapter6;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class OutputDuplicates {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        for (;;) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            prompt(scan);
        }
    }
    public static void prompt(Scanner scan) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("What is the name of the file?");
        String name = scan.next();
        File inputFile = new File(name);
        if (inputFile.exists()) {
            Scanner read = new Scanner(inputFile);
            while (read.hasNext()) {
                String line = read.nextLine();
                Scanner oneLine = new Scanner (line);
                while (oneLine.hasNext()) {
                    String word = oneLine.next();
                    System.out.println(word);
                }
            }
        } else if (!inputFile.exists()) {
            prompt(scan);
        }
    }
}
```

Any insight to the logic from here out would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sample/actual output pls

Comment: as a learner, try  to separate logic into smaller unit. For example how do you get duplicate strings from a list, how to read a line and construct a list etc.

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for the quick comments. The print statement at the end of the second while loop is just for testing purposes. In case anybody was wondering. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go buddy, it should work for you

```
public Map<String, Long> scan(File file) throws Exception {

        Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
        Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
        while (read.hasNext()) {
            String line = read.nextLine();
            if(map.containsKey(line)) {
                map.put(line, map.get(line).longValue() + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(line, 1L);
            }
        }
        
        return map;
}
```

Comment: nice! i'm going to debug this to see exactly how it works but thank you anyhow.

Comment: Yeah I'll do that! I don't have enough reputation to put a thumbs up or whatever, but I'll accept yours as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

pseudocode:

```
for each line in the file
{
 lastword = ""
 numtimes = 1
 for each word in the line
 {
  if word == lastword
  {
   numtimes++
  }
  else
  {
   if numtimes > 1
   {
    print (/*print lastword and numtimes here*/)
   }
   lastword = word
   numtimes = 1
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain it a little bit more? Sorry I don't know much, just a semester of high school java.

Comment: It will print, every time there is a word repeated, how many times it was repeated in a row. I haven't written it in Java, but you should be able to figure out what it is doing nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah I think I get what you're saying. I'll give it a whirl! Thanks Patashu.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a symbol frequency table:

```
Map<String, Integer> symbolFrequencies = new HashMap<String, int>();
```

Then for each symbol, do this:

```
Integer countForSymbol = symbolFrequencies.get(symbol);
if (countForSymbol==null){
    symbolFrequencies.put(symbol, 1);
} else {
    countForSymbol = new Integer(countForSymbol.intValue + 1);
}
```

and that's it. You will now have counts for all the symbols you have parsed.

Comment: Pretty sure the 1 in the put call will get autoboxed to an Integer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But this symbol frequency table is a little bit over my head in terms of concepts.

Comment: Learn by doing, Dude. It's a very simple data structure you will see a million times: a hashmap. All you are doing is saying I want to store a set of values, retrieved by a key. So for you to track the counts of every symbol you encounter, you have to do something like this.

Comment: So it's kind of like an array or something?

Comment: No, it's a map. An array is just a collection of items. There are no keys in an array. You could just put the symbols in an Array then go loop for them. If your assignment was just figure out which ones are dupes, that would be fine. It's not. It wants you to retain counts for each symbol, hence the Map.

Comment: Frankly, if it was just output each thing that was duped, the Set would have been the right way, because then you'd put each thing in and just call set.contains(symbol) on each and if it returns true, it's a dupe, but again, you need counts.

Comment: Ok. I think I get the basic logic behind what you're saying. So I'm going to go read up on these symbol frequency tables. I've honestly never heard of them.

Comment: It will be time well-spent. Some people seriously never progress past the map stage of development. It's super critical. Think of it as a set of cubby holes: you put something into it, using a key, you can come back and get it out using that same key, later.